# How to load multi dimensional data from Excel into relational database

Tags: sql, database, excel

[image: Build Chart]

I have an excel sheet that shows the height-weight acceptable by underwriting class (insurance). I would like to load it into a relational database table with the following columns - underwriting_class, height and weight. Is there a way to do the transformation thru' SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SSIS (Integration Services) for this as either a one time load or save the package to load as often as your data updates in the spreadsheet.

You can manage the headers and many other column properties within the package.  So, you would be able to create your new table(s) based on the pages in the workbook.

Here is a good primer on SSIS 2005

[How to import an Excel file into SQL Server 2005 using Integration Services](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205)

Comment: Thanks. I know that SSIS and similar ETL tools can do it. I was trying to see if the database engine/sql without external tools provided some support

Comment: Actually, after you sent this, I looked around more and found some additional options, depending on your server configuration and access.  If you're on a 32bit OS you can use "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 14.0;Database=C:\Folder\YourWorkbook.xlsx;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')"  This is for Excel 2010 (Excel 14.0).  If you're on 64bit SQL Server, you can create a linked server to your spreadsheet, which I haven't tried yet (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/4887d91f-6ac7-40c0-9fc8-5cdd0634e603)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming underwriting_class is in column A, height is in B and weight is in C, create column D with a formula like this:

```
="INSERT INTO some_table(underwriting_class, height, weight) VALUES ('"&A:A&"', "&B:B&", "&C:C&",);"
```

- Fill that down for all the data you have
- Copy column D and paste into Notepad
- Save as a .sql file
- Create the table in your database
- Use whatever database client you use to load your .sql file into the database

Comment: The headers there - Prefered, Select, Class 1 are examples of underwriting classes. The whole numbers in the chart are the weights.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to your spreadsheet. If A2=Preferred, A3=Select, A4=Class 1 and B2 through B4 and C2 through C4 contain your numbers, my method above should work. Without seeing your spreadsheet I can't help any further.